# Pulling Updates from Assembla with JGit

Tags: git, fetch, jgit

I can't figure out how to get `MergeCommand` working with JGit. I have my repo hosted on Assembla. On a local folder cal Git, I have a copy of the repo. I can push to assembla from this repo. On another folder called Git6, I have a clone of the remote repo.

What I want to do is do some changes on Git repo, push to assembla, and pull these changes with jgit on Git6.

So far, I can connect to assembla, I can checkout, I can fetch. My challenge is around merge and pull. Pull keeps telling me "No merge head specified". To overcome this, I decided I would do fetch and merge. I can see that the fetch is working as expected. In fact, I can do fetch through code and `git merge origin/sit` through command line to achieve the expected result.

The question is, how do I do `git merge origin/sit` through JGit?

Here is the result I get after merging with jgit:

```
Merge of revisions 9014971ef8cb9261e8a4816b067ecf82fdb7bcd2, 9014971ef8cb9261e8a4816b067ecf82fdb7bcd2 with base 9014971ef8cb9261e8a4816b067ecf82fdb7bcd2 using strategy recursive resulted in: Already-up-to-date.
```

My fetch and merge code snippets are this:

```
Git git = Git.open(f);
StoredConfig config = git.getRepository().getConfig();
config.setString("remote", "sit", "url",remoteRepoURL);
config.save();

git.checkout().setName("sit").setForce(true).call();
RefSpec spec = new RefSpec("+refs/heads/sit:refs/remotes/origin/sit");
git.fetch().setCredentialsProvider(provider).setRemote("sit").setRefSpecs(spec).call();
MergeResult r= git.merge().include(git.getRepository().getRef("sit")).setStrategy(MergeStrategy.RECURSIVE).call();
```

I suspect there is something wrong with the RefSpec or the include. But I can't figure it out. The branch I am trying to pull is called sit on ALL repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Instead of call getRef("sit") in the merge, I had to call getRef("remotes/origin/sit").